# Convert excel's NOW time format but in C++

Tags: c++, excel, time

I have a program that reads a binary file's data. One data field is the date and time in "NOW" format. This is a format used in excel as I have understood.

But I need to convert this by myself in my C++ program without excel and I cannot find any documentation on how to do so or even what NOW format means as in how excel utilizes it... So I don't know how to begin and therefore have no code I can show. I can provide an example of how a number can be converted to time in excel:

In excel a cell with value "44916.3" can be converted to: "2022-12-21  07:12:00" when formatting the cell as Time

How can I do this in C++?

Comment: In Excel, dates are integers and decimal part is the time itself. First date Excel can read is 1st January 1900 and it's the number 1, number 2 would be 2nd Jan 1900 and so on. Today is 45013. About time, it's just a rule of three. 1/24 would be exactly 01:00 and so on. so 7,12*60/24 would be 07:12:00. Don't know how to do this in C++ but at least you know how dates and times work in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double excel_date = 44373.5;
time_t unix_time = (excel_date - 25569) * 86400; // Convert to Unix time (seconds since Jan 1, 1970)
tm* tm_time = gmtime(&unix_time); // Convert to tm structure in UTC
```

The simplest way is to convert the Excel time (days since 1900) to Unix time (seconds since 1970), which just involves subtracting days and then converting days to seconds.

Comment: Nitpick:  1970-01-01 - 25569 days is 1899-12-30, not 1900-01-01.  But your formula correctly models the Lotus 1-2-3 bug that assumed 1900 was a leap year. :-)

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

[Excel uses by default the 1900 date system.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487#:%7E:text=The%201900%20date%20system,-In%20the%201900&text=This%20is%20the%20default%20date,the%20dates%20that%20you%20copied.)
In the 1900 date system, dates are calculated by using January 1, 1900, as a starting point. When you enter a date, it is converted into a serial number that represents the number of days elapsed since January 1, 1900.

This number is stored as double. So what we need to do is convert the Excel date to UnixTimestamp (seconds from 1-1-1970).

```
const double EXCEL_DATE_OFFSET = 25569.0; // days between 1900-01-01 and 1970-01-01
const double SECONDS_PER_DAY = 86400.0;

time_t excelTimeToUnixTimestamp(double excelTime) {
    double unixDate = (excelTime - EXCEL_DATE_OFFSET) * SECONDS_PER_DAY;
    return static_cast<time_t>(unixDate);
}

int main()
{
    double excelTime = 10;

    time_t unixTime = excelTimeToUnixTimestamp(excelTime);

    char str[100];
        
    time_t unixTimeToTimeT = unixTime;  
    tm timeinfo;
    localtime_s(&timeinfo, &unixTimeToTimeT);

    // format the timestamp using strftime
    strftime(str, sizeof(str), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",&timeinfo);

    // print the formatted string
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```